# Expression Tree Expression.Call Syntax

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm having some trouble pivoting an expression tree generator I built.

In essence, I want to convert the following to an expression tree:

```
var res = myObjInstance.AnalysisResponseMeasures
           .First(p => p.MeasureTypeId == 1).MeasureValue
```

So far, I've got:

```
var propertyExp =  Expression.Property(pe, "AnalysisResponseMeasures");
            var someParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(AnalysisResponseMeasure), "p");
            var someParam2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(AnalysisResponseMeasure), "p");
            var childPropExp = Expression.Equal(
                     Expression.Property(someParam, "MeasureTypeId"),
                     Expression.Constant(1));

            var firstExp = Expression.Call(
            typeof(IEnumerable<AnalysisResponseMeasure>),
            "First",
            new[] { typeof(AnalysisResponseMeasure) },
            propertyExp,
            Expression.Lambda(childPropExp, someParam2));

            var selectExp = Expression.Property(firstExp, "MeasureValue");
```

But, I get a runtime error stating that type of `IEnumerable<AnalysisResponseMeasure>` has no method `First`.

I've clearly got my parameters wrong, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: You want to call the static method [Enumerable.First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @JohanLarsson, thanks.  I'm not actually trying to call that static method though.  I'm trying to call the Linq extension method First with a lambda.

Comment: That is the method I linked to.

Comment: @JohanLarsson, that actually ultimately did help, I appreciate it.  I changed `typeof(IEnumerable<AnalysisResponseMeasure>)` to `typeof(Enumerable)`.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Played a little, maybe this works for you:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(AnalysisResponseMeasure), "p");
var prediacte = Expression.Lambda<Func<AnalysisResponseMeasure, bool>>(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(p, "MeasureTypeId"), Expression.Constant(1)), p);

var firstMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                    .Single(m => m.Name == "First" &&
                                                 m.GetParameters().Length == 2 &&
                                                 m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.IsGenericType &&
                                                 m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Func<,>))
                                    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(AnalysisResponseMeasure));
var foo = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "foo");
var first = Expression.Call(firstMethod, Expression.Property(foo, "AnalysisResponseMeasures"), prediacte);
var measureValue = Expression.Property(first, "MeasureValue");
var yourExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, double>>(measureValue, foo);
```

It is unreadable, make sure you add unit tests.

Comment: You can get the method info in more "type safe way" by:
var firstMethod = ((MethodCallExpression)((LambdaExpression)(((Expression<Func<AnalysisResponseMeasures>>)(() => default(IEnumerable<AnalysisResponseMeasures>).First(d => true))))).Body).Method;